# How can I get information that actor was termineted?

Tags: akka, actor

Let's assume that i have some root actor (created not by another actor, but somewhere else). How can i monitor this actor? How can I get information that actor was terminated ?

Comment: You can `watch` actorRef. See [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-lifecycle.html#watching-actors) for more details

Comment: But can i watch outside of the actor? I see that method watch is called on context, but as i said I want watch root actor. Or maybe you suggest create dedicated actor for watching another ?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create a parent actor and spawn a child using `actorSelection` that you can watch. After create the child actor you watch it using `context.watch(child)`. Then, once you have this child actor you send a `PoisonPill` to check if this actor is alive. Here is one simple example:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorSystem, PoisonPill, Props, Terminated}

object WatchingActors {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import ParentWatcher._
    val system = ActorSystem("WatchingActors")
    val parentWatcherActor = system.actorOf(Props[ParentWatcher], "parentWatcher")
    parentWatcherActor ! StartChild("child3")
    val child3 = system.actorSelection("/user/parentWatcher/child3")
    // make sure that child3 has been created
    child3 ! s"[1] child3, are you still there?"
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    child3 ! s"[2] child3, are you still there?"
    // SENDING A POISON PILL TO SIMULATE THE DEATH
    child3 ! PoisonPill
    for (i <- 3 to 50) child3 ! s"[$i] child3, are you still there?"
  }

  object ParentWatcher {
    case class StartChild(name: String)
    case class StopChild(name: String)
    case object Stop
  }

  // This is a better parent actor
  class ParentWatcher extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    import ParentWatcher._
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case StartChild(name) =>
        log.info(s"[ParentWatcher] Starting child $name")
        val child = context.actorOf(Props[Child], name)
        // WATCH THE ACTOR HERE
        context.watch(child)
      case Terminated(actorRef) =>
        // GET THE CHILD ACTOR REFERENCE THAT JUST DIED
        log.info(s"the reference that I am watching ${actorRef.path.name} has been stopped")
    }
  }
  class Child extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case message => log.info(message.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

Logs:

```
[1] child3, are you still there?
[2] child3, are you still there?
Message [java.lang.String] to Actor[akka://WatchingActors/user/parentWatcher/child3#1022823549] was not delivered. [1] dead letters ...
Actor[akka://WatchingActors/user/parentWatcher/child3#1022823549] was not delivered. [2] dead letters ...
....
the reference that I am watching child3 has been stopped
Message [java.lang.String] to Actor[akka://WatchingActors/user/parentWatcher/child3#1022823549] was not delivered. [6] 
...
```